# input range as timeline for a 12 hour day

Tags: javascript, html

So i'm trying to get this slider (inpute type range) to start ticking for each minute that passes as soon as I start the timer. I have not been able to find any clues about how to go about this. [image: this is what it looks like so far] The Idea is that I start a timer and the slider crosses over to the other side in 12 hours

this is my slider

```
 <input type="range" id="timeline" name="timeline" min="0" max="720">
```

Also its probably not something normal but if I could pin the current time to the slider that would look great imo. If anyone knows how to do that let me know as wel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fun idea, this should follow the current locale time of the browser.
Updates every half minute.
This will slide back to the start when it crosses 12 hours, unsure if this was your idea or not, please comment if it isn't and I'll adjust my answer.

```js
const slider = document.getElementById("timeline");

setInterval(updateSlider, 1000 * 30);

function updateSlider() {
  const now = new Date();
  const mod = now.getHours() % 12;
  slider.value = (60 * mod) + now.getMinutes();
}

updateSlider();
```

```html
 <input type="range" id="timeline" name="timeline" min="0" max="720">
```

Comment: You're welcome, remember to pick an answer so the question gets marked as answered, have a nice weekend!

Comment: I need at least 15 reputation to upvote

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you just need your slider to go one step every one minute.

You can use the `setInterval()` method to do that for you every one minute.

```js
let slider = document.getElementById("timeline")

setInterval(
    function() {
        slider.value = Number( slider.value ) + 1
    },
    60 * 1000
)
```

```html
 <input type="range" id="timeline" name="timeline" min="0" max="720">
```

And now your slider will go one step every one minute, you can set the increment value as you want, and decrement the time as you want.

The `Number( slider.value )` is just to turn the slider value from string to number because javascript reads it as a string by default.

And we multiple 60 * 1000 because `setInterval()` takes time as milliseconds, so `1000` is a second and `60 * 1000` is a minute.